# how to get the default values from the model into a new breeze clientside entity

Tags: breeze

i would like to create new entities which use the default values defined in the model.
i've checked the retrieved metadata, and the default values are there:

> {"name":"LastName","type":"Edm.String","maxLength":"50","unicode":"true","fixedLength":"false","**defaultValue**":"admin:
>   Nachname"},

however they are not taken into consideration when creating a new entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Breeze that should be fixed in the next release, out in about week. When this fix gets in then breeze will honor any defaultValues it finds in the EntityFramework data model.

One problem though is while it is easy to get 'defaultValues' into a Model First Entity Framework model via the properties editor, it's actually difficult to get it into a Code First EF model, unless you use fluent configuration. Unfortunately, EF ignores the [DefaultValue] attribute when constructing Code First model metadata.

One workaround that you can use now is to poke the 'defaultValue' directly onto any dataProperty. Something like:

```
var customerType = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Customer");
var fooProperty = customerType.getProperty("foo");
fooProperty.defaultValue = 123;
```

Comment: looking forward to the next release then, for now i'll use the documented approach `var newCust = manager.createEntity('Customer', **{name:'Acme'}**);` to fill the default values, thanks!